# How to use Javascript/JQuery to verify that at least two fields in a checkbox are selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create Javascript verification code for a form, so that each section of the form is verified after hitting "submit". I am having trouble writing the code so that the checkbox section of the form verifies that two or more boxes have been selected. I tried to start simple by writing the code so that a div, errorcheckbox, would display a message if no checkbox is selected at all. However it does not work. Here is the HTML and script for the code pertaining to the checkbox:

HTML:

```
  <form action="#" method="POST">
    <div class="contactForm">
      <label for="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox">Contactee Type: </label><br>
      <div id="errorcheckbox" class="error"></div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="type1" value="Individual">Individual<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="type2" value="Catering">Business:Catering<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="type3" value="Partner">Business:Partner<br>
    </div>

    <div class="button"><input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></div>

  </form>
```

and the Javascript:

```
    $("document").ready(function(){
      console.log("Loaded");
      $("#submit").click(function(){
        checkContactee();
      });

    $("#checkbox").change(function(){
      console.log("Something in contactee changed");
      checkContactee();
    });

    function checkContactee(){
      if (document.getElementById("checkbox").checked == false){
        $("#errorcheckbox").html("<p>You missed this field</p>");
        $("#errorcheckbox").addClass("showerror");
      }
      else{
        $("#errorregarding").html("");
        $("#errorregarding").removeClass("showerror");
      }
    }
```

Right now, the code does nothing. The errorcheckbox div doesn't appear, and there is no change in the console log if a checkbox item is selected. So, this is one problem I'm having. I still need to verify that two or more of the boxes are checked. I'm hoping to do this by adding an if else statement to the checkContactee function, but am not sure how.

Comment: You may want to review the jQuery Selectors page. `$("#checkbox")` is looking for a single element having `id="checkbox"` so 1) you probably want to add an id attribute to your checkboxes , 2) give the ids unique values (often just using the value of the `name` attribute is enough. You can find how many checked checkboxes from your form (without any other elements) with `$("input[name^='type']:checked).length`, which will work, even if you don't add the id attribute

Comment: @gordon So, I can either pass the ID of each checkbox through, or find how many there are and pass the number of checkboxes through the validation system?

Comment: If all you need to verify is how many boxes are checked, `var chkCount = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked).length` and then `chkCount` has how many and you can continue your validation logic based on `if(chkCount==0){...error handling for none checked...}`. No need to loop through all the checkboxes by id - `$("input[type='checkbox']")`returns a jQuery object with all the checkboxes. Adding `:checked` filters the jQuery object to have only the ones that are checked. The `.length` tells you how many checkboxes the jQuery holds. If that's 0, do your error; more than 0, no error :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I would recommend a couple of things. Your check boxes look like you want to capture multiple values for a contact type, so they should have the same name attribute. Each check box should have it's own label and where you have a label now you should use a `fieldset` and `legend`.

By wrapping the checkboxes in a fieldset we can then use that as part of the validation process.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  console.log("Loaded");
  $("fieldset[data-mincheckboxchecked] [type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Click")
    //Get the parent fieldset
    let $parent = $(this).closest("fieldset[data-mincheckboxchecked]");
    validateMultiCheckBox($parent);

  });
});

function validateMultiCheckBox($parent) {
  console.log($parent)
  //Get minimum checked from the data attribute
  let minCheked = $parent.data("mincheckboxchecked");
  minChecked = parseInt(minCheked, 10);

  //Get the number of checked checkboxes in the parent
  let numCheked = $parent.find("[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

  //Validation Logic
  if (numCheked < minCheked) {
    $parent.find(".error").html("<p>Please select at least " + minChecked + " option" + (minCheked !== 1 ? "s" : "") + "</p>");
    $parent.find(".error").addClass("showerror");
    return false;
  } else {
    $parent.find(".error").html("");
    $parent.find(".error").removeClass("showerror");
    return true;
  }
}

$("#submit").click(function() {
  var isValid = false;
  var multiCheckValid = true;

  //Validate each group of multi checkboxes
  $("fieldset[data-mincheckboxchecked]").each(function() {
    console.log(this);
    if (!validateMultiCheckBox($(this))) {
      multiCheckValid = false;
    }
  })

  //Normally you'e set this to return false, leaving like 
  //this for demo purposes
  console.log(multiCheckValid);
  return isValid;
});
```

```css
.error {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}

.error.showerror {
  display: block;
}

fieldset label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <div class="contactForm">
    <fieldset data-mincheckboxchecked="2">
      <legend>Contactee Type: </legend>

      <div id="errorcheckbox" class="error"></div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="contactType" value="Individual">Individual</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="contactType" value="Catering">Business:Catering</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="contactType" value="Partner">Business:Partner</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset data-mincheckboxchecked="1">
      <legend>One Required: </legend>

      <div id="errorcheckbox" class="error"></div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="oneReq" value="1">A Thing</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="oneReq" value="2">Another Thing</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="oneReq" value="3">Yet another thing</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset data-mincheckboxchecked="3">
      <legend>Top 3 Movies: Three required</legend>

      <div id="errorcheckbox" class="error"></div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="movie" value="Top Gun">Top Gun</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="movie" value="Terminator">Terminator</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="movie" value="Sound Of Music">Sound OF Music</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="movie" value="Mission Impossible">Mission Impossible</label>
    </fieldset>

  </div>

  <div class="button"><input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></div>

</form>
```

This way it's extensible and not reliant on Ids.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I've adjusted my form so that each checkbox has a label and uses fieldset. However this code isn't working when added into mine. I think there might be an error in how I've added it somewhere, but am having trouble finding out where. I did run it through a syntax checker which came up okay. Could the order in which I've added the code affect how .parent and .this work? I've never used either before and am unclear on how they work.

Comment: Make sure your code is added *after* you've included the jQuery library . Also check the error console (F12 in most browsers) for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:checked` which the selector to get the checked items.

```js
function validate() {
  console.log('Total Checked = ' + $('.contactForm input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="contactForm">
  <label for="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox">Contactee Type: </label><br>
  <div id="errorcheckbox" class="error"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type1" value="Individual">Individual<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type2" value="Catering">Business:Catering<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type3" value="Partner">Business:Partner<br>
  <button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a class for your checkboxes and select that or use tag name and type to select tags,
you are using the id of a label tag for checking checkboxes
,  use .is() method in jquery to check is checked

```
$("document").ready(function(){
      console.log("Loaded");
      $("#submit").click(function(){
        checkContactee();
      });

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
      console.log("Something in contactee changed");
      checkContactee();
    });

    function checkContactee(){
      if ($("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked'){
        $("#errorcheckbox").html("<p>You missed this field</p>");
        $("#errorcheckbox").addClass("showerror");
      }
      else{
        $("#errorregarding").html("");
        $("#errorregarding").removeClass("showerror");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`var checkedCount=$("input[name^='type']:checked).length` - this pulls all inputs, looks for those with the name beginning with "type", keep the ones that are checked, and returns how many are check (here, assigned to the `checkedCount` variable). I'll leave further validation/scolding of the user up to you